# Very simplistic style add or update

Tags: c#, css, console, extension-methods

In my library for styling the `Console` I need to be able to add or update two styles: `color` and `background-color`.

The use case is very simple. There is a string with styles that I'm building and that I update to change the color if necessary.

I divided this task into three steps:

1. *explode* the string into declarations
2. manipulate the style
3. reconstruct the style

**Example** Each of these steps has its own extension:

```
void Main()
{
    var style = "color: red;";

    style
        .ToDeclarations()
        .AddOrUpdate(
            ("color", "black"),
            ("background-color", "blue")
        )
        .ToStyle()
        .Dump();
}
```

These extensions are used by higher-level extensions that call them with `const string` for property names. I just used simple strings in LINQPad.

---

**Code** Their implementation is very straightforward. They use only LINQ and tuples.

```
public static class CssExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<(string property, string value)> ToDeclarations(
        this string style)
    {
        const string declarationPattern = @"(?<property>[a-z-]+):\s*(?<value>.+?)(;|$)";

        return
            Regex
                .Matches(style, declarationPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => (
                    property: m.Value("property").Trim(),
                    value: m.Value("value").Trim())
                );
    }

    public static IEnumerable<(string property, string value)> AddOrUpdate(
        this IEnumerable<(string property, string value)> declarations,
        params (string property, string value)[] updates)
    {
        return
            declarations
                .Concat(updates)
                .GroupBy(t => t.property)
                .Select(t => t.Last())
                .Skip(t => string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.value));
    }

    public static string ToStyle(
        this IEnumerable<(string property, string value)> declarations)
    {
        return
            declarations
                .Select(t => $"{t.property}: {t.value};")
                .Join(" ");
    }
}
```

As the use case is very simple and I also don't need to parse any complex styles so are the extensions, just a simple regex with some string manipulation.

I update the style by grouping by the `property` and pick the last one if there are mutliple ones, if there is none yet, then a new style is added. If the value happens to be `null` or `Empty` then it's removed.

---

There are three more extensions: one that I use to `Join` declarations, one `Value` shortcut for regex and a `Skip` that I use as an inverse of `Where` to use positive conditions if I want to exclude some cases.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{   
    public static string Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, values);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> Skip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        return source.Where(x => !predicate(x));
    }
}

public static class MatchExtensions
{
    public static string Value(this Match match, string groupName)
    {
        return match.Groups[groupName].Value;
    }
}
```

---

Should I still improve it in any way?

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that pops out to me (though admittedly, it is very minor) is that you're recompiling the regex every time you call `ToDeclarations`.

You could use a static `Regex` instance which compiles the expression only once. `Regex` instances are also [threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129287/is-regex-instance-thread-safe-for-matches-in-c-sharp) - so no worries there.

Thus, your code could look like:

```
private static Regex _cssRegex = new Regex("(?<property>[a-z-]+):\s*(?<value>.+?)(;|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
public static IEnumerable<(string property, string value)> ToDeclarations(this string style)
{
    return
        _cssRegex
            .Matches(style)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(m => (
                property: m.Value("property").Trim(),
                value: m.Value("value").Trim())
            );
}
```